# Geometry shaped by the houses on the basemap

Tags: qgis, basemap

I want reshape my circle so that its border doesn't cut through any houses on my basemap (Envitia). In the sense that if it does, then go around that property, as depicted in the image.

Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: A WMS service returns a **picture** of the data you can not reliably extract meaningful information from it - if you require actual data you must use a WFS or WCS endpoint to fetch actual data.

Answer (score 2):

If that is your only circle you should be able to manually reshape it using [Reshape features](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html?highlight=editing#reshape-features):

[image]